# Load records in as needed in

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

I'm using this carousel : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o

```
 lists : any;
  ...
  <owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
                        <ng-template carouselSlide *ngFor="let list of lists">
  </ng-template>
  </owl-carousel-o>
```

I have 2000 records if i load all the records once then it will be slow, can i load one by one record and manage it if user clicks on next and previous buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Theres's two ways you can achieve the desired outcome.

- Either find the length of the lists beforehand and create an array with that length. Keep track of the position of the carousel you're in and try to fetch the element from the array by index. If it's not there yet, fetch it and save it. If it's already there, just show it.
- If you don't know which element to fetch, then you're better off with trying to prefetch the entire list of the elements ids and then, once you're toggling the next/prev, fetch them by id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think first option will be good, but for the carousel array I have to include only active index element, I have to clear carousel array on previous and next button click

Comment: Or you might not even need an array. Just have a variable and update it when the users clicks any of those buttons.